# A code with latches- vhdl

Tags: vhdl

The code in the figure below creates an unnecessary latch.
a) What statement(s) should be written and where to remove it?

```
signal next_p, p: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal a, b, c, d, q, next_q: std_logic;

process(select,a,b,c,d)
begin
  if (select=”00”) then
    next_q<=a;
    next_p<=”00”;
  elsif (select=“01”) then
    next_q<=b;
    next_p<=”10”;
  elsif (select=“10”) then
    next_q<=c;
                      <------- next_P isnt assigned here (latch?)
  else
    next_q<=d;
                      <------- next_P isnt assigned here (latch?)
  end if;
end process;

process(clk)
begin
  if (clk’event and (clk=’1’)) then
    q<=next_q;
    p<=next_p;
  end if;
end process;
```

I cant really find the latch at this code.. But i have some thought that next_p in the if-else statement isn't defined which leads to a latch ? But I'm not 100 percent sure if that is the answer, can someone help me to understand where the latch occurs?

regards

a student.

Answer (score 3):

Your comments are exactly correct — if you don't assign to a signal in every branch of a conditional statement, the logic synthesizer must create a latch in order to remember the previous assignment to that signal, wherever it might have been.

Comment: ok, do you think i should remove something else from this code or is this code 100% synthesizeable ?

Comment: It's definitely sythesizable, but it will suffer from race conditions, since the latching/nonlatching behavior of `next_p` depends on two input signals. If you really want a latch there, it would be better to create an explicit synchronous process for it.

Comment: Ok i think i start gettingtthe idea of how to implement and latches and flip-flops, thx for the help dave , i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Your comments are correct.

You could improve the current code, until the fragile combinational process actually does what you intend, or you could replace the lot with a single synchronous process:

```
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    case select is
    when "00" =>
      q <= a;
      p <= "00";
    when "01" =>
      q <= b;
      p <= "10";
    when "10" =>
      q <= c;
    when others =>
      q <= d;
    end case;
  end if;
end process;
```

a bit simpler... not prone to sensitivity list errors, and because the missing assignments are in the clocked process, the old value of p will be stored in a register.